# Using string methods in EF LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation wherein two urls need to be compared, one coming in to the method and the other in the db. The one in the db may or may not be Url decoded and will have %20 for space and so on.

Here's the linq query in the method:

```
var Result = (from s in context.301Redirects
              where s.IsDeleted == false && s.Status == true && HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s.OldURL).ToUpper() == HttpUtility.UrlDecode(OldURLPath).ToUpper()
              select s.NewURL).FirstOrDefault();
              return Result;
```

Inside the method I can UrlDecode the incoming param but what about the one in the db?
This one fails because EF will not recognize UrlDecode method and throw and exception saying so.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bring the collection in memory, then perform the `UrlDecode` at that point by evaluating the query. Try:

```
var Result = (from s in context.301Redirects
              where s.IsDeleted == false && s.Status == true)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .FirstOrDefault(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s.OldURL).ToUpper() == HttpUtility.UrlDecode(OldURLPath).ToUpper();

            return Result;
```

If your database table is huge though, I'd consider creating some sort of `TRIGGER`/update script to either URL encode or decode all records, that way you don't have to check at all, you just encode/decode the parameter passed in.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` would probably be better, because it doesn't unnecessarily manifest the whole result set into memory.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I re-worked my answer because I wasn't happy with the whole collection in memory.

Comment: Doesn't it now just do what I said, which you objected to (then since deleted the comment)? Typical.

Comment: @GrantThomas I can no longer see your original answer (before you edited), but I'm sure you spoke about just doing the one check? I deleted my comment because you'd changed your answer.

Comment: No, I elaborated re the `ToList` thing - multiple checks were fundamental to the suggested routine (if both formats indeed were available).

Comment: @GrantThomas Ah well I apologise, +1 to you for the concept then, I decided to implement it for the OP.

Comment: The new answer doesn't work. `UrlEncode` is not idempotent, i.e. if OldURLPath is already URL encoded and you encode it a second time the result is different and comparing it to the value from the database that is URL encoded only once wouldn't find a match.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Do you have any documentation to prove this? I thought it was basically a glorified string replace wrapper for replacing spaces and other illegal URL characters.

Comment: Yep, needs more thorough working out, hence the idea and not a shoddy implementation.

Comment: Simple proof: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(" ")` yields `+`, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(" "))` yields `%2b`, i.e. an URL encoded `+` sign.

Comment: @GrantThomas Well why don't you post some code then? Instead of picking holes in my *shoddy* implementation. I've rolled it back to the first version, which still stands correct.

Comment: Ignoring your question due to its ignorance, I think your rollback is best suited given that it exposes a potential option that had previously been made to disappear (which it needn't have done as both routes could have been covered), whether ideal or not.

Answer (score 1):

Do your adjustments *before* the query so that you have absolute values for comparisons in the query that align with the particular formats, and always check *against* the ones in the database, rather than transform them - so, this potentially includes using `OR` in your query, instead of pulling the whole thing into memory *a la* `ToList`.